# Calculating a similarity/difference matrix from equal length strings in Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, string-comparison

I have pairs of equal-length strings in Python, and an accepted alphabet. Not all of the letters in the strings will come from the accepted alphabet. E.g.

```
str1 = 'ACGT-N?A'
str2 = 'AAGAA??T'
alphabet = 'ACGT'
```

What I want to get is a `numpy` matrix that describes the similarities and differences between the strings. I.e. columns of the matrix are letters from the accepted alphabet in `str1` and rows are letters from the accepted alphabet in `str2`. The entries are the sum of the number of times that `str1` and `str2` contain the relevant letters. I only care about cases where both strings have accepted letters at a given position.

So, for the example above, my output would be (cols are `str1`, rows are `str2`, names are in alphabetical order starting top left):

```
# cols & rows both refer to 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' starting top left
# cols are str1, rows are str2

array([[ 1,  1,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0,  0]])
```

I can brute force this by going through every possible pair of solutions, but I'd like to know if anyone has hints (or links) towards a more general solution. E.g. is there are a way to get closer to something where I can define an alphabet of N unique characters, and get out an N-by-N matrix given two equal-length input strings?

Brute force approach:

```
def matrix(s1,s2):
    m= np.zeros((4,4))
    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i]==s2[i]:
            if s1[i]=="A":
                m[0,0]=m[0,0]+1
            elif s1[i]=="C":
                m[1,1]=m[1,1]+1
            elif s1[i]=="G":
                m[2,2]=m[2,2]+1
            elif s1[i]=="T":
                m[3,3]=m[3,3]+1
        elif s1[i]=="A":
            if s2[i]=="C":
                m[1,0]=m[1,0]+1
            elif s2[i]=="G":
                m[2,0]=m[2,0]+1
            elif s2[i]=="T":
                m[3,0]=m[3,0]+1
        elif s1[i]=="C":
            if s2[i]=="A":
                m[0,1]=m[0,1]+1
            elif s2[i]=="G":
                m[2,1]=m[2,1]+1
            elif s2[i]=="T":
                m[3,1]=m[3,1]+1
        elif s1[i]=="G":
            if s2[i]=="A":
                m[0,2]=m[0,2]+1
            elif s2[i]=="C":
                m[1,2]=m[1,2]+1
            elif s2[i]=="T":
                m[3,2]=m[3,2]+1
        elif s1[i]=="T":
            if s2[i]=="C":
                m[1,3]=m[1,3]+1
            elif s2[i]=="G":
                m[2,3]=m[2,3]+1
            elif s2[i]=="A":
                m[0,3]=m[0,3]+1           
    return m
```

Comment: I guess one solution (still clunky though) is to: 

1. Get the two strings as lists of tuples
2. Keep the tuples where both entries are in `alphabet`
3. Iterate through the cross-product of `alphabet` and `alphabet` to build the matrix.

Comment: So what does the phrase *The entries are the sum of the number of times that str1 and str2 contain the relevant letters* mean?  What is meant by `sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dot product of boolean matrices (easiest way to keep the order right):

```
def simMtx(a, x, y):
    a = np.array(list(a))
    x = np.array(list(x))
    y = np.array(list(y))
    ax = (x[:, None] == a[None, :]).astype(int)
    ay = (y[:, None] == a[None, :]).astype(int)
    return np.dot(ay.T, ax)

simMtx(alphabet, str1, str2)
Out[183]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Marked as the accepted answer because it returns the output in the format requested.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done succinctly using `set`, a few comprehensions and a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) as:

**Code:**

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

def dot_product(allowed, s1, s2):
    in_s1 = {c: set([y.start() for y in [
        x for x in re.finditer(c, s1)]]) for c in allowed}
    in_s2 = {c: set([y.start() for y in [
        x for x in re.finditer(c, s2)]]) for c in allowed}
    return pd.DataFrame(
        [[len(in_s1[c1] & in_s2[c2]) for c1 in allowed] for c2 in allowed],
        columns=list(allowed),
        index=list(allowed),
    )
```

**Test Code:**

```
str1 = 'ACGT-N?A'
str2 = 'AAGAA??T'
alphabet = 'ACGT'

print(dot_product_sum(alphabet, str1, str2))
```

**Results:**

```
   A  C  G  T
A  1  1  0  1
C  0  0  0  0
G  0  0  1  0
T  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks - this seems like a good lead towards the solution. But the results are not quite what's in the question. The matrix should have sums of cases where `str1` is the column name and `str2` is the row name (this is not the same as the sum of the cross product, but I can't see how to get there from what you've got); should include zeros; and row and col names should be ordered as in `allowed`.

Comment: The result should be the matrix given in the question (i.e. mostly zeros, with a five 1's, and row & col names ordered as 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' as in the `allowed` in your solution.

The five 1's represent the five cases in which `str1` and `str2` both contain characters in `allowed`. 

Perhaps the missing info is that I am only interested in comparing identical positions in the strings (i.e. the first character in `str1` with the first in `str2`, the second in `str1` with the second in `str2`, etc).

Comment: Yes. Really it's an iteration through the string positions, just looking at whatever pair of characters you get at that position. So the five 1's in the answer represent position 0 being 'AA' (A in both strings), position 1 being 'CA' (C in `str1`, A in `str2`) etc.

Comment: Whoa. Thanks. Now I have to work to learn how/why it works. But I massively appreciate this.