# Calculating comparisson matrix using strings as input in python - HARD

Tags: python, string, numpy, matrix

I have two strings of DNA sequences and I want to compare both sequences, character by character,  in order to get a matrix with comparisson values. The general idea is to have three essential points:

1. If there is the complementary AT (A in one sequence and T in the other) then 2/3.
2. If there is the complementary CG (C in one sequence and G in the other) then 1.
3. Otherwise, 0 is returned.

For example if I have two sequences ACTG then the result would be:

```
 | A   | C  | T   | G |
A| 0   | 0  | 2/3 | 0 |
C| 0   | 0  | 0   | 1 |
T| 2/3 | 0  | 0   | 0 |
G| 0   | 1  | 0   | 0 |
```

I saw there is some help in this post
[Calculating a similarity/difference matrix from equal length strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511674/calculating-a-similarity-difference-matrix-from-equal-length-strings-in-python) and it really work if you are using only a 4 nucleotide long sequence-
I tried using a larger sequence and this error was printed:
`ValueError: shapes (5,4) and (5,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 5 (dim 0)`

I have the code in R which is

```
##2.1 Separas los strings
seq <- "ACTG"
seq1 <- unlist(as.matrix(strsplit(seq,""),ncol=nchar(seq),
                         nrow=nchar(seq)))
a <- matrix(ncol=length(seq),nrow=length(seq))
a[,1] <- seq1
a[1,] <- seq1
b <- matrix(ncol=length(a[1,]),nrow=length(a[1,]))
for (i in seq(nchar(seq))){
  for (j in seq(nchar(seq))){
    if (a[i,1] == "A" & a[1,j] == "T" | a[i,1] == "T" & a[1,j] == "A"){
      b[[i,j]] <- 2/3
      } else if (a[i,1] == "C" & a[1,j] == "G" | a[i,1] == "G" & a[1,j] == "C"){
        b[[i,j]] <- 1
      } else
        b[[i,j]] <-  0
  }
```

But I can't get it code in python.

Comment: What did you do in python and how did it fail?

Comment: @MadPhysicist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511674/calculating-a-similarity-difference-matrix-from-equal-length-strings-in-python I used the solution given in this post. But the problem is that I dont want the dot product. I want a single comparisson chracter by chracter.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're making it harder than it needs to be.

```
import numpy as np

seq1 = 'AACCTTGG'
seq2 = 'ACGTACGT'

matrix = np.zeros((len(seq1),len(seq2)))

for y,c2 in enumerate(seq2):
    for x,c1 in enumerate(seq1):
        if c1+c2 in ('TA','AT'):
            matrix[x,y] = 1.
        elif c1+c2 in ('CG','GC'):
            matrix[x,y] = 2/3

print(matrix)
```

Comment: Your inner loop variables have a typo